# how can i edit this code to remove whitespaces from right end of a string

Tags: javascript, loops

the output for '   anyvalue   ' will be 'anyvalue   '
it only removes left side whitespaces
how can I get it working to do it only to the right side of a string

I know how to use **String.prototype.replace** and **String.prototype.substring** to get it working but not in this case

```
function RmvLefttWhiteSpaces(string) {
var result = "";
var left = true;
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if (left === true) {
    if (string.charAt(i) != ' ' && string.charAt(i) != '\t' && string.charAt(i) != '\n') {
        left = false;
    } 
  }
  if (left === false) {
    result += string.charAt(i);
  }
}

return result;
```

}

I expect the output of ('    anyvalue    ') to be '    anyvalue', but the actual output is 'anyvalue    '

Comment: You mention that you expect the output of ' anyvalue ' to be ' anyvalue'.  But String.prototype.trimEnd() does this.  Namely, ' anyvalue '.trimEnd().  That is essentially what is going on in my answer.  So we may need more information on why trimEnd and other functionas aren't working in your case.

Comment: thanks I got it working with String.prototype.trimEnd()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're doing it this way for some other reason, there exists a function for you already: String.prototype.trimEnd().

```js
let val = ' anyvalue ';
let trimmed = val.trimEnd();

// frame 'trimmed' in '*' to show
// that there is no whitespace on
// the right.
console.log(`*${trimmed}*`);
```

---

**Edit(s):**

You mention that you've considered String.prototype.trimEnd() without success.  Maybe you have been thinking it's supposed to work like this:

```
String.prototype.trimEnd(' anyvalue ');
```

In fact, it's like this:

```
' anyvalue '.trimEnd();
```

The statement 'String.prototype' just means that 'trimEnd' is a method on the string *prototype*.
But ' anyvalue ' is a string *instance*, so you can call 'trimEnd' right from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.prototype.replace() with a regex.

```
function RmvLefttWhiteSpaces(string) {
    var regex = /\s+$/gm
    return string.replace(regex, "")
}
```